# Repeater items data all use source items data for data

Tags: c#, asp.net, repeater, sitecore

Okay so I have a repeater:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater"  OnItemDataBound="myRepeater_ItemDataBound" runat="server">

    <HeaderTemplate>
    </HeaderTemplate>

    <ItemTemplate>

    <sc:sublayout ID="scSublayout" Path="/Components/Spot/BlurbSpot.ascx" runat="server" />

    </ItemTemplate>

</asp:Repeater>
```

Data is binded like this:

```
myRepeater.DataSource = Sitecore.Context.Item.GetChildren();
myRepeater.DataBind();
```

My item databound gets the datasource and applies it to the sc:sublayout:

```
protected void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Item || e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.AlternatingItem)
    {
        var scSublayout = e.Item.FindControl("scSublayout") as Sitecore.Web.UI.WebControls.Sublayout;

         if (scSublayout != null)
         {
             scSublayout.DataSource = ((Sitecore.Data.Items.Item)e.Item.DataItem).ID.ToString();
         }
    }
}
```

It display two items, but both items display data from the second datasource. Debugging I can see it finds both, but the original values for the 1st loop get written over for some reason.

What I want is both items being display, and the first item that gets looped over not to have its variables written over.

@Mark Ursino

```
public partial class BlurbSpotSublayout : Logic.BaseSublayout
{

    public static string Blurb_Spot_Heading;
    public static string Blurb_Spot_SubHeading;
    public static string Blurb_Spot_Abstract;

    private void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) 
    {
        if (DataSource != null)
        {
            Blurb_Spot_Heading = BlurbSpot.GetInstance(DataSource.Paths.FullPath.ToString()).Heading;
            Blurb_Spot_SubHeading = BlurbSpot.GetInstance(DataSource.Paths.FullPath.ToString()).SubHeading;
            Blurb_Spot_Abstract = BlurbSpot.GetInstance(DataSource.Paths.FullPath.ToString()).BlurbAbstract;
        }

    }
```

Front-end is:

```
<div ID="Div3" runat="server"><%=Blurb_Spot_SubHeading%></div>
<div ID="Div1" runat="server"><%=Blurb_Spot_Heading %></div>
<div ID="Div2" runat="server"><%=Blurb_Spot_Abstract%></div>
```

Then I pass the item to a class behind by doing:

```
Database webDB = Sitecore.Configuration.Factory.GetDatabase("web");
Sitecore.Data.Items.Item item;
this.item = webDB.Items[item];
```

GetInstance().Heading does this:

```
public string Heading
    {
        get
        {
            if (item != null)
            {

                    Sitecore.Data.Fields.Field field = item.Fields["BlurbSpot_Content_Header"];

                    if (field != null)
                    {
                        return field.Value;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return _heading; // returns default pixel width if BlurbSpot_Heading is not define, or is null
                    }
            }

            return _heading;

        }

        set
        {
            _heading = value;
        }
    }
```

Comment: Please provide the code your your sublayout UserControl.

Comment: Thats quite a bit, I know but I resolved it following yoru article. In the code behind you have `sctHeadline.DataSource = ` it equals nothing in yoru article so it was a bit misleading I have changed it to `sctHeadline.DataSource = DataSource.Paths.FullPath.ToString();`

Comment: I will edit this article at home and add the answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that your strings are declared statically as:

```
public static string Blurb_Spot_Heading;
public static string Blurb_Spot_SubHeading;
public static string Blurb_Spot_Abstract;
```

Because they are static they are shared across all instances of the user control. Declare them as:

```
public string Blurb_Spot_Heading;
public string Blurb_Spot_SubHeading;
public string Blurb_Spot_Abstract;
```

Give it a shot.

Comment: Looks like your right there is well, haha solved in two ways. Not a good day for me as a programmer such basic errors. Thanks for the correction.